# Android - get proximity sensor min and max value

Tags: android, sensors, proximity

The app i am building makes use of the proximity sensor. Trying it in different phones i found that the proximity sensor has different (min,max) values in different phones (my htc sensation has 0 for covered and 9 for uncovered while xperia has 0 for covered and 1 for uncovered).So the question is:
 How do i get the proximity sensor's min max values ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think minimum value for proximity Sensor is `0` for all devices. and to get maximum range...

```
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor proximitySensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    proximitySensor.getMaximumRange();
```

Comment: `minimum value for proximity Sensor is 0` is true for all devices. For example, for some of `Motorola Moto G`, min is `3 cm` and max is `100 cm`

Answer (score 4):

According documentation :

```
Some proximity sensors only support a binary near or far measurement.
In this case, the sensor should report its maximum range value in the far state
and a lesser value in the near state
```

So proximity sensor could even had no min and max values. Then you should just compare its value with `proximitySensor.getMaximumRange()`.

Answer (score 0):

Each proximity sensor is different. You have to monitor the values in onSensorChanged() and remember min and max value. It's working fine. Here is my code for checking near state.

```
    private float proximityCalibratedMax = Float.MIN_VALUE;

    ...

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            if(event.values[0] > proximityCalibratedMax){
                proximityCalibratedMax = event.values[0];
            }

            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY && proximityCalibratedMax != Float.MIN_VALUE) {
                if (event.values[0] < proximityCalibratedMax) {
                    prevNear = true;
                    sensorTimestamp = new Date().getTime();

                } else {
                    long currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
                    prevNear = false;
                    openAutifyCarMode();

                }
            }
        }
```